# Read path location and export it to mysql table

Tags: c#, mysql

I'm using the code below to read path location and export it to mysql table:

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Stream myStream;

        OpenFileDialog openFileDialog1 = new OpenFileDialog();
        if(openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
        {
            if ((myStream = openFileDialog1.OpenFile())!=null)
            {
                string strfilename = openFileDialog1.FileName;
                string filetext = File.ReadAllText(strfilename);
```

but it's named as follows:
'C:UsersmeDesktopProjectSongsHello Lyrics.txt'

instead of
'C:\Users\me\Desktop\Project\Songs\Hello Lyrics.txt'

In addition i need to copy just the name of the file.
In this case "Hello Lyrics.txt"

How it can be done?

Comment: There's nothing in this code that would be stripping out characters.  And if you need the name of the file, use the `Path` class to extract it from the full path: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
// this is your code:-
string strfilename = openFileDialog1.FileName;

// Now try this:-
string fileNameOnly= Path.GetFileName(strfilename);
```

To get file name use "GetFileName" method and pass it the filepath.

For more reference:-

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getfilename(v=vs.110).aspx

so if you have your filePath stored in the string variable `"strfilename"` use that to extract your fileName with the Path class.

Comment: But the files are changing.

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by the files are changing... you wanted to get the filename out of the strFilename variable...so I was trying to show you how you can extract it. Can you explain a bit more?

Comment: I edited the question.
I'm using button2 to choose diffrent file each time

Comment: Ok, everytime you click button2, your event calls the click method...you open a new file...hence your filePath changes along with it... Now use the code I have shown to extract the file name into a string variable and then you can do whatever you want with that fileName

Comment: Great, it's working.
Now i can export only the file name to mysql.
You solved my second problem.
I still have a problem to copy the path with '\'

Comment: put a break point in your code and show me what strfilename shows for value ? Looking at the code, my guess is there is some formatting error somewhere. but not in the above posted code.